# Split a path when it's not connected

Tags: inkscape

By converting an image from raster to vector, I have created a path in inkscape:

[image: path in inkscape]

I'm desperatelly clicking all the *Path* buttons when I'm trying to turn the letters into individual objects. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

1. *Path → Break Apart*
2. Select the ı and its dot.
3. *Path → Combine*